# Javascript to keep expandable list open

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, expand, tile

I am coding a website and currently have 3 list items that expand and shrink onClick. The 3rd list item contains a contact form and I would like it to not shrink when the form fields are clicked on, but still shrink if any other part of the list item is clicked. Is this possible?  Here is the HTML and Javascript I am currently using

```
<ul class="tiles">
  <li class="tiles__tile" data-tile="1">
    <h2>About</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="tiles__tile" data-tile="2">
    <h2>Work</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="tiles__tile" data-tile="3">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<li class="content__item" id="3">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <h2> GET IN TOUCH </h2>
    <form class="form" id="form1" method="post" action="" method="post"/>
      <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name"/>
      </p>

      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </p>

      <p class="text">
        <textarea name="comment" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
      </p>


      <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue" href=""/>
        <div class="ease"></div>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</form>



    <li class="content__item" id="3">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <h2> GET IN TOUCH </h2>
    <form class="form" id="form1" method="post" action="" method="post"/>
      <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name"/>
      </p>

      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </p>

      <p class="text">
        <textarea name="comment" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
      </p>


      <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue" href="dillonpropp.com"/>
        <div class="ease"></div>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</form>



 var tileBtn = $('li.tiles__tile');
var allContent = $('li.content__item');
var contentWrap = $('.content-wrap');

tileBtn.on('click touchstart', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var match = self.attr('data-tile');
  var allContent = $('li.content__item');
  var content = $('li#' + match);

  self.toggleClass('active');

  content.toggleClass('active');

 contentWrap.css({'transition-delay': '.35s'});

  return false;
});

$(window).on('click touchstart', function() {
  if (allContent.hasClass('active') && tileBtn.hasClass('active')) {
    allContent.removeClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      tileBtn.removeClass('active');
    }, 400);
    contentWrap.css({'transition-delay': '.0s'});

  }
})
```

Comment: The shared code doesn't shrink when the `content__item` is clicked... it toggles on the title click... so you have some other click handler also

Comment: try to recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0khydvvc/1/

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Is there a way for me to keep the content__item with id="3" active until the submit button is clicked? I just want people to be able to click on the form fields and fill them out without it toggling away from the form.

Comment: which means there is some other code in your page that is doing this....

Comment: try to add the last click handler - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0khydvvc/2/

Comment: Adding the last click handler prevents all of the list items from expanding at all now....I can't see how any other code could be doing this since that is only JS I am using on this site. Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you share the complete html.... may be the actual html structure is causing it... update the fiddle and try to recreate the problem... then share the updated link

Comment: Here is the problem recreated on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0khydvvc/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the handlers attached to the window object.

```js
var tileBtn = $('li.tiles__tile');
var allContent = $('li.content__item');
var contentWrap = $('.content-wrap');

tileBtn.on('click touchstart', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var match = self.attr('data-tile');
  var allContent = $('li.content__item');
  var content = $('li#' + match);

  self.toggleClass('active');

  content.toggleClass('active');

  contentWrap.css({
    'transition-delay': '.35s'
  });

  return false;
});

$(window).on('click touchstart', function(e) {
  if (allContent.hasClass('active') && tileBtn.hasClass('active') && !$(e.target).is('.content__item :input')) {
    allContent.removeClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      tileBtn.removeClass('active');
    }, 400);
    contentWrap.css({
      'transition-delay': '.0s'
    });

  }
})
```

```css
.content__item {
  display: none;
}
.content__item.active {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tiles">
  <li class="tiles__tile" data-tile="1">
    <h2>About</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="tiles__tile" data-tile="2">
    <h2>Work</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="tiles__tile" data-tile="3">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="content__item" id="1">1</li>
  <li class="content__item" id="2">2</li>
  <li class="content__item" id="3">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <h2> GET IN TOUCH </h2>

      <form class="form" id="form1" method="post" action="" method="post">
        <p class="name">
          <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
        </p>
        <p class="email">
          <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </p>
        <p class="text">
          <textarea name="comment" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
        </p>
        <div class="submit">
          <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue" href="dillonpropp.com" />
          <div class="ease"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```